# Codeigniter Load header and footer only once

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm developing an admin portal using Codeigniter. Here i want to load the header and footer and sidebar only once and change the main content without loading the header and footer everytime.
Please provide some good reference which i can refer. I dont want to go about with the ajax technique since im using angular js I think codeigniter templates will be the right approach but im new to codeigniter templates. So some good links to template tutorials would be preferable.
Thanks in advance

Comment: without refresh and without ajax ... then use angular js

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh: thanks for the quick reply. Can u provide me with some reference or some brief example??

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

Please make seperate Header.php and footer.php and load as below

Make function in controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $data['result'] =$this->db
                              ->get('product')
                              ->result();

        $this->load->view('users/header');
        $this->load->view('users/product_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('users/footer');


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter you can load a view inside other view, then yo can do a complex structure like:

- in your controller load the primary view with:

  `$this->load->view('default', array('page' => 'your_page'));`
- and in the view `views/default.php`:

  `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
      </head>
      <body class="background" style="font-family: calibri;" id="contentprincipal">
          <header>
              <?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>
          </header>
          <section class="contents">
              <?php $this->load->view($page); ?>
          </section>
          <footer>
              <?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
          </footer>
      </body>
  </html>`

You can reuse `default` for every "page".

But, if you are building a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) or don't want a complete page reload on every link you need client side code (Javascript). Codeigniter is PHP, server side; on every page load header and footer are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jose thanks for your insight & for the questions Gautam.

> $this->load->view('virtual_accounts/default', array('page' =>
>   'va_page','data' => $data));

I just realized that you can also send data to a view inside the array declared, thought I should share.